# How to handle warnings in code (not compiler)

Tags: functional-programming

Say you have functions A, B, and C.  A will be called and then call B then B calls C.  C loops on a bunch of stuff.  C determines there is a warning that the user should at least be made aware of but it doesnt block the process.  How would you communicate these warnings to A?

If i pass a list to use for warnings from A to B, then its passed straight through to C as B has no use for it.  Exceptions would halt C from continuing its loop.

Is this a normal problems?  What are elegant ways to solve it?

EDIT: code example

```
def A():
    items = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
    ]
    try:
        B(items)
    except Exception, e:
        print e

def B(items):
    for num_list in items:
        if len(num_list) == 0:
            raise ValueError('A numberlist cannot be emtpy')

        C(num_list)

def C(numbers):
    for num in numbers:
        if num > 9:
            ## -- Warning???
            print '%i is greater than 9, this might break things'

        print num
```

Comment: It is always helpful to provide an actual code example (even though it is broken, or incomplete) for others to fix it. Language does not matter.

Comment: What makes you think B "has no use for" a warning list? A calls B to get something done, including getting it set appropriately. B sets it appropriately by passing it when calling C. Just get clear in your mind what global state change and return value every function is to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have A pass a function that can write to a log of some sort down to B and then C, which C could then call to make a note of the warnings. If you're using a language that supports *parameters* like Racket, then you could use those. Note that this doesn't refer to function arguments, in Racket parameters are a mechanism for handling state in a threadsafe and much more elegant style. Essentially a parameter is a variable that you can mutate only for a specific portion of code, and it automatically rolls back the changes after exiting, even with unexpected control flows such as exceptions or continuation jumps. I know of no languages other than Racket that offer this construct however.